# Extending object class in Java

Tags: java

As we know every class in java extends object class, so how java does not follow the multiple inheritance

For Ex class A it will implicitly extends the object class, and we have class B which also implicitly extends the object class.

So now when we extend class A with class B then logically it extends Class B and class object which is multiple inheritance

Can any body give the explanation for this.

Comment: http://www.instanceofjava.com/2014/12/why-java-does-not-supports-multiple.html loads of information out there

Comment: Who told you that java is not multiple inheritance ?

Comment: @Abderrahim it is the basic functionality of java, you can google it and find this

Comment: @nitinlalwani please are you sure that java is not multiple inheritance ?!

Comment: @Abderrahim yes i am sure